# Warning Unexpected unnamed function func-names under, ESLint rule

Tags: javascript, eslint, rules

My `eslint` version is 4.18.2, it would give a warning like this:

> Unexpected unnamed function
>    Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

When defining functions in such a way:

```
 const farmerIds = a.reduce((function (hash) {
  return function (prev, curr) {
    !hash[curr.farmerId] && (hash[curr.farmerId] = prev.push(curr));
    return prev;
  };
}(Object.create(null))), []);
```

Comment: You can disable the rule by following this instructions: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/func-names or you could extract the unnamed function and put it under a constant.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

These are two different issues…

**Unexpected unnamed function**

This is, as pointed out by Constantin, the ESLint rule [func-names](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/func-names).

If you don't want to disable this rule, you can either use names for your functions, like so:

```
const farmerIds = a.reduce((function reducer(hash) {
  return function fn(prev, curr) {
    !hash[curr.farmerId] && (hash[curr.farmerId] = prev.push(curr));
    return prev;
  };
}(Object.create(null))), []);
```

Or, and this I would recommend personally, use arrow functions:

```
const farmerIds = a.reduce(
  (hash => {
    return (prev, curr) => {
      !hash[curr.farmerId] && (hash[curr.farmerId] = prev.push(curr));
      return prev;
    };
  })(Object.create(null)),
  []
);
```

**Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression**

ESLint is complaining about this line, which is indeed an expression, not an assignment or function call:

```
!hash[curr.farmerId] && (hash[curr.farmerId] = prev.push(curr));
```

You can rewrite it as an `if` statement:

```
if (!hash[curr.farmerId]) {
  hash[curr.farmerId] = prev.push(curr);
}
```

**Fixing both**

Putting the code examples above together, this code should run without ESLint complaining:

```
const farmerIds = a.reduce(
  (hash => (prev, curr) => {
    if (!hash[curr.farmerId]) {
      hash[curr.farmerId] = prev.push(curr);
    }
    return prev;
  })(Object.create(null)),
  []
);
```

Note that I've also removed the curly braces around the body of the first arrow function, which is a nice additional feature of arrows to keep the code more concise.

Comment: i still get warning "Unexpected unnamed function"

Comment: Did you try to extract the `function (hash) {}` into `const FUNCTIONNAME = function (hash) {}` and then use it in your reduce.

Comment: I've updated my answer, you have two different ESLint warnings

Comment: Thanks for the beginning of the fix for `Unexpected unnamed function`, but just as a heads up, newer ESLint throws `Expected parentheses around arrow function argument having a body with curly braces. (arrow-parens)` for that second suggestion. I had to change it to like `(hash) =>` and remove the trailing paranthesis you added later on.

Answer (score 3):

Another simple way is give the `underscore` as the function name. For example:

`const farmerIds = a.reduce((function _(hash) {...}(...);`

Answer (score 0):

If we need to export without declaring, it can be used as below

```
export default () => {

// your code goes here

}
```

Comment: This won't work if you need access to `this`